# How can I create a stored procedure for a log table

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging

I am looking for an answer to create a stored procedure for a log table. Below is the scenario for which I need to write that SP.

Whenever user logs in or logs out store LOG-IN and LOG-OUT time with user's unique LOGIN-ID.

Also I have to restrict the user from logging in if users previous session is terminated abnormally or user closed the application without proper log out then user needs to wait for 10 mins before next login.

This is what I tried:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_CHECKER(@LOGINID VARCHAR(70))
AS
 BEGIN
    DECLARE @LASTID INT,@CURRENTTIME DATETIME,@TEMP INT,@HAS VARCHAR(30)
    SELECT TOP 1 SLNO, @TEMP=(DATEDIFF(MI,LOGINDATETIME,GETDATE()))  FROM TBL_LOGINDETAILS ORDER BY SlNo DESC

    SET @HAS=(SELECT LoginID FROM TBL_LOGINDETAILS WHERE LogoutDateTime IS NULL)
  IF @HAS IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN 
    IF(@TEMP >= '10' )
      BEGIN   
       SET @CURRENTTIME = (SELECT DATEADD(MI, -10, GETDATE())) 
       UPDATE  TBL_LOGINDETAILS SET LogoutDateTime=@CURRENTTIME WHERE SLNO=@LASTID
      END
  ELSE
    RETURN @LASTID  
   --PREVENT FROM LOGIN 
  END 
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO TBL_LOGINDETAILS (LoginID,LoginDateTime,isLogged) VALUES(@LOGINID,GETDATE(),'1')   
END
```

Comment: So you already **have** your stored procedure - so what's the question, **exactly**??

Comment: ya i have...but there are some performance issue's. My TL gives a dread-look when i showed it to her...HHAH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what i tried.

```
        USE [DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[USP_SetLoginStatus]    Script Date: 11/28/2011 10:58:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_SetLogStatus] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @PLoginName     Varchar(75)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @SNO INT    --VARIABLE TO HOLD THE SERAIL NUMBER
   ,@ISLOGGED BIT       --HOLDING IS LOGGED STATUS 
   ,@TIMEDIFF VARCHAR(50) --VARIABLE TO HOLD TIME DIFFERENCE BETWEEN CURRENT LOGIN AND LAST LOG OUT TIME

    -- SELECT QUERY FOR GETTING @TIMEDIFF AND SERIAL-NO VALUES FOR USER

     SELECT @SNO=[SlNo],@ISLOGGED=[isLogged] ,@TIMEDIFF =DATEDIFF(MI,
     (SELECT TOP (1) [LoginDateTime] FROM TBL_LOGINDETAILS WHERE [LogoutDateTime] IS NULL ORDER BY [SlNo] ),
     GETDATE()) FROM TBL_LOGINDETAILS WHERE [LoginID]=@PLoginName

    --IF USER IS LOGIN FIRST TIME 

    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT isLogged FROM TBL_LOGINDETAILS WHERE [LoginID]=@PLoginName)  
     INSERT INTO TBL_LOGINDETAILS(LoginID,isLogged,LoginDateTime) VALUES(@PLoginName,'1',GETDATE()) 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
      IF (@TIMEDIFF >=10) --LOGOUT TIME DIFF IS MORE THAN OR EQUALS TO 10 MINUTE 

   BEGIN
      ----- UPDATING LOGOUT AND IS LOGGED FIELD
       IF(@ISLOGGED =1 )
        BEGIN
          UPDATE  TBL_LOGINDETAILS SET [LOGOUTDATETIME]= (SELECT DATEADD(MI, -10, GETDATE()) ), [isLogged]=0 WHERE [LoginID]=@PLoginName
          AND [SlNo]=@SNO

      ----- INSERTING NEW LOG FOR CURRENT USER

         INSERT INTO TBL_LOGINDETAILS([LoginID],[LoginDateTime],[isLogged]) VALUES(@PLoginName,GETDATE(),1)
        END
     ELSE
       UPDATE  TBL_LOGINDETAILS SET [LOGOUTDATETIME]= GETDATE() , [isLogged]=0 WHERE [LoginID]=@PLoginName AND [SlNo]=@SNO
    END  
  ELSE

    RETURN '0'  
    END

END
```

Comment: Have you posted the answer from your side? Or you need a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The one thing that jumps out is the fact you have a variable called `@TEMP` of type `INT` - but you're comparing as if it were a string:

```
IF(@TEMP >= '10' )   -- unnecessary single quotes! You're comparing against a string literal...
BEGIN   
       SET @CURRENTTIME = (SELECT DATEADD(MI, -10, GETDATE())) 
       UPDATE  TBL_LOGINDETAILS SET LogoutDateTime=@CURRENTTIME WHERE SLNO=@LASTID
END
```

It's an INT - so you need to compare it against a numeric value:

```
IF(@TEMP >= 10)  -- **NO** unnecessary single quotes....
BEGIN   
   UPDATE dbo.TBL_LOGINDETAILS 
   SET LogoutDateTime = DATEADD(MI, -10, GETDATE())
   WHERE SLNO = @LASTID
END
```

Also - I'm **sure** you can find a more suitable, more meaningful and more obvious name for this variable than `@TEMP` ....